# I imported tensorflow as tf in notebook and run it successfully, but when I used tf.__version__ it says NameError: name 'tf' is not defined. Help me

Tags: python, tensorflow, virtual, virtual-environment

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZlNv.png) The first block ran without any errors. but second says name error tf not defined even though i have imported tensorflow as tf.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, simply

```
   import tensorflow as tf
   print(tf.__version__)
```

Additionally, check this is installed.

Comment: I did exactly the same . you can see it in the image that i have attached. the problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the CMD in the administrator mode and install the libraries using pip install
2. pip show  to check the path where it is installed.
3. Import the path using the following code:

import sys

sys.path.append('c:/users/admin/appdata/roaming/python/python39/site-packages')
sys.path.append('c:/python/python39/lib/site-packages')

The path will vary as in step 2.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest rolling tensorflow back to a previous stable version, in this case. It might be a bug with the current version.